# Passing value from typescript to routerlink

Tags: angular, typescript, routerlink

I have a property in my typescript file

subject.component.ts

```
subject: string; 
this.subject = "angular";
```

I want to pass this to my routerlink in my HTML file

subject.component.html

```
[routerLink]="[subject,'area']"
```

app.routes.ts

```
  path: 'angular',
  component: SubjectComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'area',
      component: AreaComponent,
      data: { subject: 'angular' }
    }
  path: 'angular2',
  component: SubjectComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'area',
      component: AreaComponent,
      data: { subject: 'angular2' }
    }
```

but I am having problems as it is not resolving out.
The page requested is not being returned. I am re-directed to home-screen

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: the page requested is not being returned. I am re-directed to homescreen.

Comment: Can you post your TS and HTML?

Comment: as you not assign anything to  subject property.. so it will return undefined

Comment: You didn't declare a route that can handle this path. Please provide your routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set query params and fragment as follows:

```
// subject = 'sss' ; set in your component otherwise it wont be added.
```

`<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{sub: subject }" fragment="education"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

see the  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdflq9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) demo

compare this code and figure it out what you did wrong

i have added in `app.component.html` is

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<a [routerLink]="[subject,'area']"> Redirect</a>
```

in `app.component.ts`

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  subject:string;

  ngOnInit(){
     this.subject = 'test';
  }
}
```

and in `app.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test/area', component: HelloComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem I was having was related to the relative path of the link I was trying to access. The change I made was to add a leading forward slash

subject.component.html

[routerLink]="['/',subject,'area']"